# How to use Xrandr to crop off cracked screen in Multi screen setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have two monitors, Laptop(1366x768) and a secondary display(1366x768). On my secondary display I have a crack in the right side of the screen which I want to avoid. I have tried using

```
xrandr --fb 2732x1536 \
--output eDP-1 --fb 1366x768 \
--output DP-1  --fb 1266x768 --transform 1,0,-100,0,1,0,0,0,1
```

here eDP-1 is my laptop screen and DP-1 is my secondary display. when I run this the contents from eDP-1 bleeds into DP-1 for 100 pixels and then DP-1 starts and the contents of DP-1 on the right side get cut off thus making it difficult to go full screen on DP-1 as the right side is cut off.

A screenshot of the setup and the difficulty faced:

[image]